# Explain Select max without Groupby

Tags: sql

I see the following query and I don't understand:
The whole query works but if I run the subquery, No such column Measure.measure_date.
Please explain me how it works?
Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM Measure 
WHERE measure_time =(SELECT Max(measure_time) FROM Measure f 
WHERE f.measure_date= Measure.measure_date 
AND f.measure_date >= date('2021-01-01')  
AND f.measure_date <= date('2021-20-01')) 
AND measure_category_id = '3' ORDER BY  measure_date ASC;
```

When I tried to run subquery, it threw error: No such column Measure.measure_date. But if I run the whole query, it does work.

```
SELECT Max(measure_time) FROM Measure f 
    WHERE f.measure_date= Measure.measure_date 
    AND f.measure_date >= date('2021-01-01')  
    AND f.measure_date <= date('2021-20-01')
```

This is my data:
[image]

Comment: *What* error did you get?

Comment: I think - "WHERE f.measure_date= Measure.measure_date" is a problem, you have only one table here so Measure. is incorrect.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the full error message you got (as text, no screen shots please)

Comment: I added above.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to this subquery:

```
WHERE measure_time =(SELECT Max(f.measure_time)
                     FROM Measure f 
                     WHERE f.measure_date = Measure.measure_date AND
                           f.measure_date >= date('2021-01-01') AND
                           f.measure_date <= date('2021-20-01')
                    )
```

This is an example of a *correlated, scalar subquery*.

It is a subquery for obvious reasons -- a query within a query.

It is a *scalar subquery* because it returns one column and zero or one rows.  Hence, it can be used (almost anywhere) where an expression can be used.  It returns one row because of the `MAX()`.  An aggregation query (i.e. one that uses aggregation functions) but has no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row.  If there are no rows to process, the value of the aggregation function would be `NULL` or `0`.

It is a *correlated scalar subquery* because the `WHERE` clauses refer to the outer query, in this condition:

```
WHERE f.measure_date = Measure.measure_date
```

Conceptually, this means that the subquery is run for each row in the outer query.  Of course, the SQL optimizer determines the actual execution plan, which might be different from the conceptual understanding.

Comment: Your answer helps me to fully understand. Thanks :).